# He helps terraform Mars, and then regrets it

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I saw a story on TV when I was a child (in the 80s) that involved a man working from earth to transform the climate of Mars. Then, later, he travels to the surface of Mars, and discovers the corpses of Martian life forms everywhere, which I remember as being made of a lot of squidgy tubes, like octopi or kelp (not humanoid at any rate). He's filled with heartbreak and regret.

I'm pretty sure this isn't from one of the adaptations of The Martian Chronicles.

Comment: By any chance is this same one described in [this SF&F SE question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71330/sci-fi-film-about-terraforming-venus-inadvertently-killing-the-native-worm-like) ? The descriptions (different planets not withstanding) are pretty similar....

Comment: That was one of the first questions I tried to help ID here on SF&F, good to see it finally has an answer.

Comment: This certainly appears to be a duplicate.

Comment: @Richard Don't you think the **other** question should be closed, seeing as this one at least got the right planet?

Comment: @user14111 - The answer is the dupe bit, not the question.

Comment: @user14111 actually, I'm not entirely sure who got the planet right...there are a few sites where people have tried to ID this film, and some people say it was Mars, some say Venus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going off the question I linked to in my comment above, the film appears to be ["Mind-slaughter"](http://www.worldcat.org/title/mind-slaughter/oclc/5641207&referer=brief_results) (1977), part of the Kentucky Educational Television (KET) series "Universe and I".

[WorldCat.org description](http://www.worldcat.org/title/mind-slaughter/oclc/5641207&referer=brief_results):

> Presents basic planetary life support principles and man's potential
>   impact on other planets with a tale about an experiment to create an
>   atmosphere for human habitation on another planet which ends in
>   killing an intelligent life form already there.

Comment from a user on a [Discover magazine article](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/badastronomy/2009/08/02/xkcd-and-b612/#.VPINyOGwl2k):

> . . . In high school earth science class, we watched a short film
>   called “Mind Slaughter”. It was about a project to terraform Mars. A
>   manned visit to the terraformed planet discovered that there was
>   previously undiscovered subterranean intelligent life on Mars, that
>   had been wiped out by the effects of terraforming. The deceased
>   “intelligent life” was modeled using dryer hose.

Dryer hose:
[image]