# Spock and links to Sherlock Holmes?

Tags: star-trek

In the 1992 book *Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country* by J M Dillard, Spock comments "An ancestor of mine maintained that if you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains – however improbable – must be the truth".

This is a phrase most associated with Sir Arthur Conan Doyle's character *Sherlock Holmes*. Has it ever been explored whether Spock's mother was a descendant of Doyle's?

Comment: The line is taken directly from the film :"*An ancestor of mine maintained that when you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth. If we did not fire those torpedoes, another ship did."*

Comment: NB Leonard Nimoy played a Sherlock Holmes pastiche in a 1977 educational film named ["Interior Motive"](https://vimeo.com/112218871) (or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_rKfRpQZEE)). See [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/277415/4318).

Comment: An ancestor of Spock could have been quoting Sherlock Holmes without actually having any family ties to Conan Doyle. Spock's statement doesn't preclude the possibility that his ancestry merely included a devout Holmes fan

Comment: I do like your avatar! :D

Comment: @AnthonyX - Or just referring to Conan Doyle as an ancestor (e.g. a human from an earlier era)

Comment: **Q.** *Star Trek VI is also the film in which Spock calls Sherlock Holmes "an ancestor of mine."* **Nicholas Meyer:** *He implies it.*; - http://www.grouchoreviews.com/interviews/7

Comment: @FreeMan I have slightly more hair than Wallace

Comment: @Giacomo1968 and of course there's the whole thing about Shakespeare in the "original Klingon"

Comment: The reality of course is that Meyer is messing with you. He is poking a bit of fun at the tendency of SciFi fans to obsessively try to reconcile every piece of factual information from their preferred works, by introducing fun but seemingly impossible facts. Enjoy the facts, and maybe have fun speculating about their relevance, but don't expect an answer.

Comment: And, of course, "*There's an old Vulcan proverb: Only Nixon could go to China.*" and other self-referential tongue-in-cheek lines. The author is signalling in bright, clear terms that they know Vulcans are a fictional projection of some human characteristics, and that they intend to have a bit of fun exploring that. Do not take every utterance literally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spock is, according to the film's scriptwriter Nicholas Meyer, **a descendant of Sherlock Holmes**. Quite how such a thing is possible, given that Holmes is a fictional character, is left to the imagination of the viewer.

> What Spock says is a nearly exact quotation from Sherlock Holmes:
> “Depend upon it, my dear Watson, once you have eliminated all the
> other possibilities, the remaining one, however improbable, is the
> correct solution.” Hence, Holmes is Spock’s ancestor.
>
> Elementary! And fascinating.
>
> Nicholas Meyer, who directed and co-wrote the new Star Trek movie,
> confirms that this is what he meant by the line. “Clearly, you have
> understood my intention,” he said Tuesday, speaking by phone from
> London, where he lives.
>
> <sub><sup>[SPOCK SECRET: ELEMENTARY, MY DEAR TREKKIES](https://www.orlandosentinel.com/1991/12/04/spock-secret-elementary-my-dear-trekkies/)</sup></sub>

It would appear that Meyer added this line *specifically [to create mystery and generate discussion](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheWalrusWasPaul)*, despite it not making logical sense that he's related to Holmes.

> “I have a good time watching the movie when I see it with a (preview)
> audience, because there are enough Holmes buffs in the audience that
> people go nuts when that line comes up,” Meyer added. “And they go,
> ‘Oh, my God! Oh, my God! Is this possible?’ And the answer is: I don’t
> know if it’s possible. It’s what Spock said.”
>
> [..]
>
> For the most fanatical Star Trek fans, however, the idea that Spock is descended from Holmes might seem utterly preposterous. After all, true Trekkies may insist, Holmes is only a fictional character while Spock, of course, is real.
>
> A Sherlock Holmes buff to the core, Meyer has an answer to that:
>
> **“Who says Holmes is fictional?”**

---

The issue of Spock's ancient human ancestry was, to the best of my knowledge not discussed in any subsequent works, and certainly not in the films or TV shows. The problems is, of course compounded by the fact that **Holmes is latterly shown to have been a fictional character within the Star Trek universe**.

> **DATA:** *There. I have instructed the computer to give us a Sherlock Holmes-type problem, but not one written specifically by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: Elementary, My dear Data](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/129.htm)</sup></sub>

Of course, there's the unexplored possibility that Spock is, via the magic of time travel, in fact *Holmes himself*, as evidenced by the historical holo-image below.

> [image]

Comment: It's sometimes painful to make sense of Meyer's work: _Undiscovered Country_ is the _Rise of Skywalker_ of Star Treks.

Comment: Spock might be claiming to be a descendant of the *non*-fictional  Arthur Conan Doyle, who, after all, authored the statement.

Comment: If that really was Meyer's intent, he wasn't paying attention to Trek canon. According to Wikipedia, the script for ST6 was completed in 1990 (film released Dec 1991) while TNG: "Elementary, Dear Data" aired in 1988, already establishing Conan Doyle as a historical figure and author of the fictional Sherlock Holmes within the Trek universe, and TNG: "Unification" (1991) solidly  included Spock in the TNG universe (at least indirectly mentioned all the way back in the TNG pilot). Meyer should have had ample time to avoid the obvious canon conflict.

Comment: It might be useful to add some information about the last image. A reverse image search tells me it shows Leonard Nimoy in a play called 'Sherlock Holmes' by William Gillette in 1975/6.

Comment: @lexible - Meyer states that Spock is the descendant of Holmes, not Doyle.

Comment: This is an easy solution. In the Star Trek universe there *was* a real Sherlock Holmes, on whom Conan Doyle based his works. That makes it possible both that Spock is his descendant and that Data can talk about Holmes mysteries written by Conan Doyle (be they real-life mysteries that he is retelling in fictional form, or ones he made up and attributed to the fictional Holmes).

Comment: "Quite how such a thing is possible, given that Holmes is a fictional character.."  Well, Spock is also a fictional character, so why not? ;)

Comment: @Astrogator - Both the interviewer and Meyer [play that game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQMwe.png). The interviewer points out that as far as trekkies are concerned, Spock is real and Holmes isn't. Meyer points out that Holmes is real and that Spock is fictional ;-)

Comment: I thought we're looking at things from perspective of real world :).  My bad )))

Comment: @Valorum Eh... Meyer says a lot of things.

Comment: As I understand it, Star Trek is *supposed* to be a fictional extrapolation on our real world, at least to TOS production era. So, our history and the fictional Trek history are shared up to that point. Obviously the World War III and "Eugenics Wars" (history for Kirk, Spock, etc.) were speculative as of their mention in TOS, so the Trek universe has diverged from ours. However, the shared past remains shared - including notables such as Byron, Milton, Shakespeare, Brahms, and Conan Doyle. Meyer may have been playing with the fans with that remark, but it would tie up Trek canon in knots.

Comment: @AnthonyX, I wonder if in-universe it's true that Spock is related to Holmes/Conan Doyle — how in heck have they kept lineage records through all those apocalyptic wars they had on Earth in their universe?

Comment: @user28434 - Time travel, obviously

Comment: @Valorum, ah yeah, forgot that it's pretty common for them